# How to Check if a Set is Convex?

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

I am wondering to practically check the convexity of a set. I understood the definition but, in practice, how can we check the convexity of a set, especially if it is defined in higher spaces.

If you can show me, maybe solving these two examples, I'll appreciate your help!

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzJeB.png)

Comment: You can start by proving some basic facts and then building up from them: the half-space defined by a hyperplane is convex, a ball in any norm is convex, the epigraph of a convex function is convex, intersection of convex sets is convex and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is convex because for any two pints in it the entire line segment from one to the other is in it. The second one is not convex: $(0,n)$ and $(n,0)$ belong to it but $\frac 1 2 (n,0)+\frac 1 2 (0,n)$ does not if $n >2$.

For the first set you can also use triangle inequality for the usual norm on $\mathbb R^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me the first example using triangle inequality? How could I approach the problem?

Comment: The given set is $\{(x,y): \|(x,y)\|<2\}$. If $ \|(x,y)\|<2$ and $\|(x',y')\|<2\}$ then, for any $t \in (0,1)$ we have $\|t(x,y)+(1-t)(x',y')\| \leq t \|(x,y)\|+(1-t)\|(x',y')\|<t(2)+(1-t)2=2$.